# How to install Java 8 on Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: java

I have a machine with a version of Ubuntu 20.10 installed. I would like to install Java 8.

```
java -version
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72, or
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2~20.10
sudo apt install openjdk-13-jre-headless  # version 13.0.7+5-0ubuntu1~20.10
sudo apt install openjdk-15-jre-headless  # version 15.0.3+3-1~20.10
sudo apt install openjdk-16-jre-headless  # version 16.0.1+9-1~20.10
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~20.10
sudo apt install openjdk-14-jre-headless  # version 14.0.2+12-1
```

If I try to do install it with the command

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

I get the following error

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~20.10
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~20.10_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Please upgrade to (or fresh install) Ubuntu 22.04. The version of Ubuntu you are running has reached end of life, and the software repositories are no longer available.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi thank you

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades